# Selecting set of binary sequences to avoid similarity

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary, sequence

I want to be able to programatically generate a set of binary sequences of a given length whilst avoiding similarity between any two sequences.
I'll define 'similar' between two sequences thus:

If sequence A can be converted to sequence B (or B to A) by bit-shifting A (non-circularly) and padding with 0s, A and B are similar (**note**: bit-shifting is allowed on only *one* of the sequences otherwise both could always be shifted to a sequence of just 0s)

For example: `A = 01010101` `B = 10101010` `C = 10010010`

In this example, A and B are similar because a single left-shift of A results in B (A << 1 = B). A and C are *not* similar because no bit-shifting of one can result in the other.

A **set** of sequences is defined is dissimilar if no subset of size 2 is similar.

I believe there could be multiple sets for a given sequence length and presumably the size of the set will be significantly less than the total possibilities (total possibilities = 2 ^ sequence length).

I need a way to generate a set for a given sequence length. Does an algorithm exist that can achieve this? Selecting sequences one at a time and checking against all previously selected sequences is not acceptable for my use case (but may have to be if a better method doesn't exist!).

I've tried generating sets of integers based on primes numbers and also the golden ratio, then converting to binary. This seemed like it might be a viable method, but I have been unable to get it to work as expected.

**Update**: I have written a function in C# to that uses a prime number modulo to generate the set without success. Also I've tried using the Fibonacci sequence which finds a mostly dissimilar set, but of a size that is very small compared to the number of possibilities:

```
    private List<string> GetSequencesFib(int sequenceLength)
    {
        var sequences = new List<string>();
        long current = 21;
        long prev = 13;
        long prev2 = 8;
        long size = (long)Math.Pow(2, sequenceLength);

        while (current < size)
        {
            current = prev + prev2;
            sequences.Add(current.ToBitString(sequenceLength));                
            prev2 = prev;
            prev = current;
        }

        return sequences;
    }
```

This generates a set of sequences of size 41 that is roughly 60% dissimilar (`sequenceLength = 32`). It is started at 21 since lower values produce sequences of mostly 0s which are similar to any other sequence.

By relaxing the conditions of similarity to only allowing a small number of successive bit-shifts, the proportion of dissimilar sequences approaches 100%. This may be acceptable in my use case.

**Update 2**:

I've implemented a function following DCHE's suggestion, by selecting all odd numbers greater than half the maximum value for a given sequence length:

```
    private static List<string> GetSequencesOdd(int length)
    {
        var sequences = new List<string>();
        long max = (long)(Math.Pow(2, length));
        long quarterMax = max / 4;

        for (long n = quarterMax * 2 + 1; n < max; n += 2)
        {
            sequences.Add(n.ToBitString(length));
        }

        return sequences;
    }
```

This produces an entirely dissimilar set as per my requirements. I can see why this works mathematically as well.

Comment: What is the exact non-similarity requirement? You could easily generate sequences by creating one at random except the MSB and LSB must be 1, and then flipping the bits in the middle using any strategy you like (e.g. trivial case: increment counter and XOR it with the middle bits) as many times as necessary. The MSB and LSB being 1 guarantee that no amount of shifting of any of the generated values will be similar to any other. But in this case the sequences would "look very similar" even though technically your requirement is met.

Comment: @Jon The sequences will be received with the possibility of being bit-shifted and the leading or trailing bits being lost (zeroed). The sequences need to be uniquely identified. By initially choosing the possible sequences according to the above definition, I hope to avoid misidentification. I'll attempt an implementation of your suggestion and update later. A working implementation is needed, but I'm also very interested in the mathematics behind the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't prove it, but from my experimenting, I think that your set is the odd integers greater than half of the largest number in binary. E.g. for bit sets of length 3, max integer is 7, so the set is 5 and 7 (101, 111).

Comment: Wouldn't 2 (010) be in that set too? And possibly 000?

Comment: 010 is similar to 101 (shift 101 right one), and anything is similar to 000, just shift anything right (or left) 3.

Comment: Yeah:

9 (1001) similar to (0001, 0010, 0100, 1000) 
11 (1101) similar to (0011, 0110, 1010, 1100) 
13 (1011) similar to (0101) 
15 (1111) similar to (0111, 1110)

Comment: This looks promising! Greater than half the max integer sets MSB to 1 and odd sets LSB to 1 which matches the comment on the question. I'll do some testing and see if this is what I'm after

Comment: This fits my requirements exactly. Perhaps you could elaborate your answer and maybe add a code snippet for future readers?